# Cannot reinstall trim into a can recessed light

Tags: lighting, recessed-lighting

I have about 15 of these same recessed lighting fixtures in my home, all with MR16 halogens. To change them I grab the edge of the trim and pull down - takes from force but it comes out, then swap the bulb and pop back in.

I have one fixture though that I cannot get the trim to go back. The fixture was fine before I changed it. When I pulled out the trim with the bulb attached, some drywall came out. It seems as if the can has pulled back into the ceiling because of broken drywall. When I try to re-insert the trim, it just falls out immediately. I think the issue is that the can has pulled into the ceiling, so the trim doesn't reach the clips and won't stay in place.

I have no idea how to fix it though - there are these two black clips that looked like they grabbed onto the edge of the ceiling, but now they are sucken in. I tried twisting the can so it could grab onto better drywall, but there's a strong tension preventing that, and preventing me from pulling it out at all - it pulls out maybe half and inch but that's it, and returns when I release it. I looked through the thing but couldn't find any spring, screws, or anything indicating where that tension is coming from.
Super frustrating because was just changing a bulb that I've done for years and now I've got this dangling bulb I cannot fix. I tried searching for issues, but almost all resources I found were about LED trims and such.

[image][image][image]

Comment: It would really help us understand the problem if you had posted a picture of the trim in question... can you add one please?